# Is $scope.$on('$destroy,function(){}); called every time a user navigates away from a view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to clear all $intervals and remove all eventlisteners when the user presses the browser back button. Can I count on $destroy being called when the user navigates away from the view(presses the back button etc ), or should I place this logic in  a custom function and assign it to window.popstate ?

```
$scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
    $scope.log_output("destroying scope and calling clearInterval");
    $scope.clearInterval();
    removeeventlistener();
});
```

Comment: Where is your `$destroy` attached? Controller?

Comment: @RGraham yes in my controller

Comment: Then yes, that'll be called each time the view switches controllers, i.e. back button

Comment: @RGraham, Ok thanks, just wanted to make double sure. Post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.